# setTimeout in for loop (1 timeout then loop at once) (double loop)

Tags: javascript, loops, timer

I followed the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values), however, this doesn't seem to work for me.
I have a first 2 dimensional array, I want to timeout between every outer loop and not timeout in the outer loop.

Here's a snippet of [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdcrab5n/9/) showing one of the three ways I tried, from the aforementioned question as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949066/settimeout-in-for-loop-fires-all-at-once) (cf. case 1, 2 and 3).

```js
    var data = [
                [
                    ["data[0][0]"],  
                    ["data[0][1]"]
                ],
                [
                    ["data[1][0]"],
                    ["data[1][1]"]
                ],
                [
                    ["data[2][0]"],
                    ["data[2][1]"]
                ]
            ]; 

    var delay = 1000;
    
        function doSomething(i) {
     setTimeout(function() {
       for(let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(data[i][j]);
        $('#result').html($('#result').html() + data[i][j]);
        }
      }, delay);
    }
    
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     doSomething(i);
    }
```

```html
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

More questions/answers on the subject tend to yield the same result so I am at a loss.

Comment: What is it doing differently than you would expect? Is it because all the `setTimeout`s are completing at roughly the same time, after about a second?

Comment: @David784 I want it to do [0][0] + [0][1], then after a second, [1][0] + [1][1] and after another second [2][0] + [2][1]. So a delay between each "i loops" and no delay between "j loops".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how the `setTimeout` works. It's not a `sleep` command where it stops the for loop. Rather, it is blazing through the initial for loop, and starting three timers at roughly the same time, to last for one second each. That means they also all end at about the same time.

You can get your desired outcome by doing something more like this (notice the `i*delay` for the timer on the `setTimeout`. That way your first timer is for 0ms, second for 1000ms, third for 2000ms, and you get the staggered results you're after.

```js
var data = [
  [
    ["data[0][0]"],
    ["data[0][1]"]
  ],
  [
    ["data[1][0]"],
    ["data[1][1]"]
  ],
  [
    ["data[2][0]"],
    ["data[2][1]"]
  ]
];

var delay = 1000;

function doSomething(i) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      console.log(data[i][j]);
      $('#result').html($('#result').html() + data[i][j]);
    }
  }, i*delay);
}

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  doSomething(i);
}
```

```html
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This *i fix makes sense indeed, i hate myself for not trying that. However, why do all those answers I found not use that even though it's the exact same setup? And they are marked as solution.

Comment: The first answer in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949066/settimeout-in-for-loop-fires-all-at-once 

does pretty much exactly what David is doing.

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this, I lost track. And i'm adding to the pile. :(

Comment: No worries...some of those other questions seemed to have more of a focus on the old var hoisting issue. Sometimes it's nice to have different questions with narrower focuses...so I wouldn't think of it as clutter :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for this problem (using a recursive idea) is to implement a method that call to itself every `1 second` until reach the last iteration (break condition), when the `index` of the outter array is equal to his length:

```js
var data = [
  [["data[0][0]"], ["data[0][1]"]],
  [["data[1][0]"], ["data[1][1]"]],
  [["data[2][0]"], ["data[2][1]"]]
];

function doSomething(i, delay)
{
    // Break condition.

    if (i >= data.length)
        return;

    // Print the inner array.

    data[i].forEach(x =>
    {
        console.log(x);
        $('#result').html($('#result').html() + x);
    });

    // Call to itself after some time to execute next iteration.

    setTimeout(() => doSomething(i + 1, delay), delay);
}

// Start the procedure.

doSomething(0, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: That is a good solution, I tried to wrap my brain around doing exactly that, but the double loop messed up my thought process for the recursion.