# How do you create a delay inside a recursive loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, delay

So I was trying to create a visual representation of bubble sort using some CSS animations and JS. The animation is supposed to have 10 numbers in bubbles, and the bubbles will float up get compared and swapped if necessary. The problem I have is I can't seem to delay the animations to  actually let individual bubbles float while the rest are dormant. I tried using recursive loops that take the indexes of the array and give individual elements the "bounce" animation, and another function that gets rid of the animation after some time. Here is the code.

```js
function animateUp(index){
    if(index < 9){
       document.getElementById("elem-" + index).style.animation = "bounce 500ms";
       document.getElementById("elem-" + index+1).style.animation = "bounce 500ms";
       setTimeout(stopAnimationByIndex(index), 600);
       setTimeout(stopAnimationByIndex(index+1), 600);
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
    
    setTimeout(animateUp(index + 1), 700);
}

function sort(){
    animateUp(0);
}
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="visual-rep">
        <div class="arr-container">
            <div class="arr" id="elem-0"></div>
            <div class="arr" id="elem-1"></div>
            <div class="arr" id="elem-2"></div>
            <div class="arr" id="elem-3"></div>
            <div class="arr" id="elem-4"></div>
            <div class="arr" id="elem-5"></div>
            <div class="arr" id="elem-6"></div>
            <div class="arr" id="elem-7"></div>
            <div class="arr" id="elem-8"></div>
            <div class="arr" id="elem-9"></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button class="sort" onclick="sort()">Sort</button>
</div>
```

I later call the function when a button is clicked. The animation doesn't work and there is no delay in the animation all the bubbles are assigned the animation at the same time and there is no delay between them. This doesn't seem to work so is there an another way for me to do this?

Comment: Can you add the HTML and CSS, so we can see it?

Comment: also: [setTimeout in for loop fires all at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949066/settimeout-in-for-loop-fires-all-at-once)

Comment: @trincot I have edited the question to include the html and css.